# How to show animated popup in Android

Tags: android, popup, android-custom-view

I'm looking for a way to make a popup (not `Dialog`) like it is in Whatsapp when you click on a profil picture.

Something like this. How do this work in Android? What do I'm looking for?

I want to show some Informations if a user clicks on a ImageView in my ListView Header.

Until now I open a new Activity if the `ImageView` is clicked.

```
holder.projectImageImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context1, JobInfo.class);
            intent.putExtra("projectInfo", projectItems);
            intent.putExtra("distributorInfo", distributorItems);
            intent.putExtra("contractorInfo", contractorItems);
            context1.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

This Code is inside a CustomAdapter which extends `BaseAdapter`.

Is there any way to do what I want?

Kind Regards!

Comment: Add ZoomIn and ZoomOut in your click

Comment: Try  popwindow we can set animations to popup window http://mrbool.com/how-to-implement-popup-window-in-android/28285

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Layout` for a custom `Dialog` with `TextView` that you need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFF" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Ok "
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and in your `Activity`, in `onClick()`

```
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
    dialog.setTitle("Title...");

    // set the custom dialog components - text and button
    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText("Your Text");

    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
        dialog.show();
```

Comment: Thank you! the solution was so easy!

Answer (score 8):

You can set dialog window enter animation and exit animation in style and can set in dialog using this-

```
<style name="animationdialog">
    <item name="@android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/dialog_in</item>
    <item name="@android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/dialog_out</item>
</style>


  dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(),android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog_NoActionBar);
  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_layout_dialog);
  dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.animationdialog;
```

dialog_in.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <scale

        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="0.3"
        android:fromYScale="0.3"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

dialog_out.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="0.0"
        android:toYScale="0.0" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />

</set>
```

Comment: very nice solution! but I cant use `getActivity()` in CustomAdapter.

Comment: you can use activity instance this by passing in custom adapter constructor

Comment: is it possible to change the background color in dialog_out in order to get a shade?

Comment: You can use onDismiss listener.
 dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.glassblack);
            }
        });